# Pipeline error Search Application Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I have an error when I start my content analysis on the search service application:

***`Le traitement de l'élément a été abandonné, car le pipeline n'a pas répondu dans le délai approprié. Une nouvelle tentative aura lieu lors de la prochaine analyse. ( CSSFeeder generated callback: The system has not received callback for the document; ; SearchID = 62B17499-A00C-4D5F-AA8D-C109AC6A253F )`***

This error corresponds to 60000 files and I can not solve it

[image]

Help Me

Tanguy

Answer (score 0):

Restarting "SharePoint search host controller" services on server.

Start a full crawl for your content source, compare the result.

Similar issue post for your reference:

[Error in SharePoint 2013 Search service application - ULS log attach](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/165819/error-in-sharepoint-2013-search-service-application-uls-log-attach)

Comment: I already made this solution and I also uninstalled and reinstalled my search service application completely

Answer (score 0):

I found this error in the sharepoint logs as a result of my first error

**`Transaction failed in IPOC plug-in Urs sts4: // sharepoint`**